# How to get a returned value from powershell and get it in a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a powershell from a batch file with the commande:
Powershell .\nameoffile.ps1

The PowerShell returns some values 1, 4, 0 and -1 . How can I get these values from the batch? When I use %errorlevel% it only returns 0 (which means that the script is okay). I have also tried using the Exit command in PowerShell (Exit 4) but It does not work.
Can you help me?

**EDIT** 
I have found a solution if someone is interested.

> `powershell "&{.\test.ps1 %* ;exit $LastExitCode}"  set code=%errorlevel%`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
powershell "&{.\test.ps1 %* ;exit $LastExitCode}" set code=%errorlevel%
```

Comment: "Unexpected token 'set' in expression or statement"

Answer (score 17):

If you need to use this value in your `bat` environment use `FOR /F` :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell .\test.ps1') do Set "$Value=%%a"

Echo Value received from Powershell : %$Value%
```

Comment: Hi Sacha, That's will work but it will not log the powershell file. It will be executed in background.

Comment: Why is the dollar sign there in `$Value`? can it be `$Value -> anythingAtAll`?

Comment: You can remove the $ char and put value if you want!

Comment: Getting a `%%a was unexpected at this time" on windows server 2016, although it works everywhere else I've tested.

Comment: Hi Chris do you use a .bat file if its direct in the PS console use %a in place of %%a

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit late to answer this question, but I would like to give it a try just in case any one needs more detailed solution. So, here it goes.

I created a batch function that would execute ps script for you and return a value, something like this:

```
:: A function that would execute powershell script and return a value from it.
:: <PassPSCMD> pass the powreshell command, notice that you need to add any returning value witth Write-Host
:: <RetValue> the returned value
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <RetValue>
  for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i in (`Powershell %1`) do set returnValue=%%i
  set "%2=%returnValue%"
Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
```

Now, as an example to use it:

```
set psCmd="&{ Write-Host 'You got it';}"
call :RunPS %psCmd% RetValue
echo %RetValue%
```

This will display on console screen You got it

As a more complicated example, I would add:

Let's assume that we want to check if a VM is Up or Down, meaning if it's powered on or off, so we can do the following:

```
 :CheckMachineUpOrDown <returnResult> <passedMachineName>
   set userName=vCenterAdministratorAccount
   set passWord=vCenterAdminPW
   set vCenterName=vcenter.somedmain.whatever
   set psCmd="&{Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; Connect-VIServer -server %%vCenterName%% -User %userName% -Password %passWord%; $vmServer = Get-VM %2;Write-Host ($vmServer.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn')}"

   call :RunPS %psCmd% RetValue
   if "%RetValue%" EQU "True" (set "%1=Up") else (set "%1=Down")
 Goto:eof

:: A function that would execute powershell script and return a value from it.
:: <PassPSCMD> pass the powreshell command, notice that you need to add any returning value witth Write-Host
:: <RetValue> the returned value
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <RetValue>
  for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i in (`Powershell %1`) do set returnValue=%%i
  set "%2=%returnValue%"
  Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
```

Now, how to use :CheckMachineUpOrDown function?

just follow this example:

```
set Workstation=MyVMName
call :CheckMachineUpOrDown VMStatus %Workstation%
echo %VMStatus%
```

This will display Up if the VM is Powered On or Down if the machine is Off.

Comment: Without an additional function, as in the example with VM, Powershell does not return control. When you insert an intermediate function, everything is OK.:SetCmd <returnResult> <RetValue>
  set psCmd="&{Write-Host You_got_it;Break Script}"
  call :RunPS %psCmd% RetValue
 Goto:eof

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an example of working with Powershell without additional .ps1 files for a very long time.

Comment: https://newbedev.com/how-to-get-a-returned-value-from-powershell-and-get-it-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
powershell .\test.ps1 >output.log
type output.log
```

It just redirects the output of the powershell script to a text file and then outputs the contents of the text file to the console.

Here is my **test.ps1** file

```
Write-Output "Hello World"
Exit
```

And here is the output:

> C:\temp\batchtest>test.bat
>
> Hello World
>
> C:\temp\batchtest>

Comment: Hi Scott thanks for your comment. But I don't want to create a new file. I have found a method, I will refresh my post

Answer (score -1):

You can use tee-object.

This will display the returned value in host console.