# How can I return multiple values from a powershell script to the batch file that is calling it?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How can I return multiple values from a powershell script to the batch file that is calling it?

I have a powershell script that returns multiple values.  I want to call it from a batch file and have each individual value go into  an individual variable in the batch file.

Only been able to return one value

The powershell code (pstest.ps1):

```
 $p1=11
 $p2=22
 $p3=33
 exit
```

The batch file:

```
 powershell .\pstest.ps1
 :: now I'd like to get those 3 returned values 
 :: into 3 individual variables so that I can do something like this:
 @echo First is %p1%, Second is %p2%, Third is %p3%
```

So, it should display this:

```
 First is 11, Second is 22, Third is 33
```

Comment: [This question might be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34451444/5096287) Not a duplicate

Comment: have you looked at setting them as user environment variables? perhaps something done with `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` would work.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: A PowerShell script called from `cmd.exe` invariably runs in a _child process_, so it cannot set environment variables that the caller will see.

Comment: I may be having a senior moment, but I wasn't expecting that Powershell code to output anything. Surely your just setting values to variables, no output is expected generally in scripting languages when setting variables.

Comment: @mklement0 - i have used what i showed to have a PoSh shell set an ENV variable that was available after the PoSh script ended. the EnvVar was available in a CMD shell started after the PoSh shell exited. try this in a PoSh shell >>> `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestEnvVar', 'Value', 'user')` <<< and then open a CMD shell and type `set`. you will see the EnvVar & its value ... so it seems like it otta work.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Yes, you can _persistently_ set an environment variable for _future_ `cmd.exe` sessions - but that's not the use case at hand.

Comment: @mklement0 - ah! i thot that created the EnvVar in the parent scope. thanks for the clarification. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

In the exact same way you get several values from any application: *one per line*...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "i=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('powershell "$p1=11; $p2=22; $p3=33; $p1; $p2; $p3"') do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "p!i!=%%a"
)

echo First is %p1%, Second is %p2%, Third is %p3%
```

I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) about *arrays*...

Answer (score 1):

<sup>For a more flexible solution using delayed expansion that doesn't require making the PowerShell script output all values on a single line and works with a variable number of outputs, see [Aacini's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584454/45375).</sup>

---

Assuming that the number of values is fixed and known in advance:

- Make the PowerShell script output a *single line* containing all the values with a *known separator*.
- In the batch file, use `for /f "delims=... tokens=..."` to capture the values in discrete loop variables, which you can assign to regular variables.

A simplified example that uses a PowerShell command to produce a single-line output with 3 values separated by `|` (to apply this to your scenario, use `-File` with your `*.ps1` file instead of `-c` (`-Command`) with a command string):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=| tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ('powershell -c " '11|22|33' "') do set "p1=%%a" & set "p2=%%b" & set "p3=%%c"

:: echo the values of the newly created variables
echo p1: [%p1%]
echo p2: [%p2%]
echo p3: [%p3%]
```

The above yields:

```
p1: [11]
p2: [22]
p3: [33]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using environment variables, you could try something like this base on SachaDee's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455939/8291949):

PS:

```
function get-multiplereturnvalues {
  "11"
  "22"
  "33"
}
get-multiplereturnvalues
```

BATCH/CMD

```
@echo First is %p1%, Second is %p2%, Third is %p3%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell .\multi.ps1') do @echo "$Value=%%a"
```

Which outputs:

```
"$Value=11"
"$Value=22"
"$Value=33"
```

Comment: The request is _"and have each individual value go into an individual variable in the batch file"_, not just _show_ the values...

Answer (score 0):

Within the PowerShell script I‘d create a temp file with the results. Within the batch file, after calling the PowerShell script, I‘d parse that temp file with FOR /F in order to get the results and set environment variables as required.