# Trying to launch powershell script from .bat file and get a value returned

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Using information I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451444/how-to-get-a-returned-value-from-powershell-and-get-it-in-a-batch-file), I am still unable to get this to work.

I have created the following `.bat` file, to call the PowerShell script on Windows 10 Professional.

```bash
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned ".\dang.ps1"') do (set "$crap=%%a")
powershell.exe .\dang.ps1
echo %$crap%
```

You will notice that it calls the PowerShell script two different ways.

This is the PowerShell script which is being launched from the batch file.

```
$crap="Pain in my butt"
return $crap
```

The strange thing is about this.  When the batch file tries to launch the PowerShell script from the `for /f` loop, I receive the following error message:

```
C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap=program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." )

C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap=At line:1 char:1" )

C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap=+ .\dang.ps1

:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap=+ ~~~~~~~~~~~" )

C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap=    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\dang.ps1String) [], CommandNotFoundException" )

C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap=    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException" )

C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>(set "$crap= " )
```

BUT, when I launch the same PowerShell script, (see last line of batch file), without using the `for /f`, it has no problem executing the script.

```
C:\Users\pgmrd\My Drive\DLSR Notes and backup\Software\Scripts>powershell.exe .\dang.ps1
Pain in my butt
```

The scripts I typed are very stripped down so that I could concentrate on making it work. BUT, the final batch file runs some backups.  Will launch the PowerShell script to read a xml file and return a file path.  Then use that file path in the rest of the backup batch file.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
:: Note the use of -File
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File ".\dang.ps1"') do set "$crap=%%a"
```

Use the `-File` parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, when invoking a *script file* (`.ps1`), which ensures that:

- script file paths *with spaces* are correctly recognized
- all subsequent arguments are passed through to the script *without additional interpretation* (except possibly by the calling shell).

Note that [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, now *defaults* to `-File`, whereas `powershell.exe` defaults to `-Command`, which is what happened in your case.

- Passing a `"..."`-enclosed `.ps1` script path to `-Command` is *not* enough, because *unescaped* `"` chars. are *stripped* before PowerShell interprets the resulting argument(s) *as PowerShell code* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458726/45375) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much mklement0, I was feeling stupid.  Still do actually.  I thought I tried the -file before.  But I don't think I wrapped .\dang.ps1 in ".  This just made my powershell script  very portable between different dos batch files.  I was going to write the output to a file and then read that, but that just leaves junk files laing around.  And there is a ton of information in that xml file that I can use for other applications. Again, thank you..  Dan